# .NET Google Api Client You cannot sign up for Google Apps because one or more of your subscriptions are in a suspended state

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-dotnet-client

Please Help,
I have error when I try to create customer with transfer token with latest API version. Below is my package version:

```
<package id="Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1" version="1.12.0.341" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Google.Apis.Admin.Reports.reports_v1" version="1.12.0.316" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Google.Apis.Auth" version="1.10.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Google.Apis.Core" version="1.10.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Google.Apis.Reseller.v1" version="1.12.0.453" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Google.Apis.Reseller.v1sandbox" version="1.12.0.453" targetFramework="net40" />
```

Below is the error details:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError You cannot sign up for Google Apps because one or more of your subscriptions are in a suspended state. [412] Errors [ Message[You cannot sign up for Google Apps because one or more of your subscriptions are in a suspended state.] Location[If-Match - header] Reason[conditionNotMet] Domain[global] ] Source: Google.Apis Stack Trace: at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute() in C:\Users\mdril\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ClientServiceRequest.cs:line 102
```

Before using this version I never get error when create customer with transfer token.

Regards,
Edwin

Comment: Hi, Is it possible for me to get a sample of the code you are using? Since you were able to get it to work see.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36864319/authentication-error-using-google-directory-api-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a client library issue.  I think you should check Google developers console and check your billing options.  I think either your credit card has expired or you forgot to pay your bill.

Your account is suspended so you cant make any requests.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct. I checked the domain status and the result is "Suspended".