# Authentication Error using Google Directory API from C#

Tags: c#, authentication, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to call the Google Apps Directory API so that I can list users to my organization's Google Apps Account

I have scoured for hours through their documentation and have been able to come up with the code below. However, I get the following error. ***Invalid Credentials [401]*** I suspect that it has to do with the way I constructed the ServiceAccountCredential

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Google Directory Service API");
        Console.WriteLine("================================");
        try
        {
            new Program().Run().Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private async Task Run()
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream("../../client-secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            JObject clientJObject = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());

            var secrets = new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = clientJObject.GetValue("client_id").ToString(),
                ClientSecret = clientJObject.GetValue("private_key").ToString()
            };

            var tokenUrl = clientJObject.GetValue("token_uri").ToString();

            var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(secrets.ClientId, tokenUrl).FromPrivateKey(secrets.ClientSecret));

            var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "My Directory Listing App",
            };

            var service = new DirectoryService(initializer);

            var users = await service.Users.List().ExecuteAsync();
            users.UsersValue.ToList().ForEach(u =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(u.PrimaryEmail);
            });
        }
    }
```

My Secrets.Json file is a bit like follows. I removed the majority of the private key part

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "service.account",
  "private_key_id": "fd6f98b603dd5a065c87a8d34a4e428cf6277a35",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "service.account@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "102588765356663060837",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/service.account%40appspot.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Administration

Step 1: Login to the Admin console

Step 2: Ensure API Access is enabled `Security > Api Reference > Enable API Access`

Step 3: Enable Google Apps Domain-wide Delegation

- Head over to the [Dev Console](http://console.developer.google.com)
- Select the API Project
- Then go to `Credentials > Manage Service Accounts > "Edit Service Account" > Enable Google Apps Domain-wide Delegation`
- `"Go Back" > "View ClientID"`
- Copy the Client ID as you'll be needing that

Step 4: Register API Client and Scopes `Security > Advanced Settings > Manage API client access`

- Enter the client ID and a comma separated list of scopes (i.e. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user)
- Then `Authorize`

Step 5: Create Service Account Private Key

- `Create Credentials > Service Account Key > "Select Service Account" > P12 "For backward compatibility with code using the P12 format" > Close`
- This will automatically download the Key code to your system. Save this key as it is very important

## The Code

First you need to install the following packages

```
install-package Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1
install-package Newtonsoft.Json
```

And finally the code below

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace GoogleApis
{

    /// <summary>
    /// This sample demonstrates the simplest use case for a Service Account service.
    /// The certificate needs to be downloaded from the Google Developers Console
    /// <see cref="https://console.developers.google.com/">
    ///   "Create another client ID..." -> "Service Account" -> Download the certificate,
    ///   rename it as "key.p12" and add it to the project. Don't forget to change the Build action
    ///   to "Content" and the Copy to Output Directory to "Copy if newer".
    /// </summary>
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Service account Email 
            //NOTE: This is the account for the Service Client
            string serviceAccountEmail = "service.account@appspot.gserviceaccount.com";

            //Path to Downloaded Key
            var path = @"Path\To\key.p12";

            //Generate a Certificate using the Key downloaded from the Api Console
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(path, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            //Create the Credential
            ServiceAccountCredential serviceCredential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
               {
                   //Define the Scopes You want the credential to Access
                   Scopes = new[]
                   {
                       DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser,
                   },
                   //Specify the User that this service Credential is Impersonating. Typically your Google Apps Admin Account
                   User = "admin@domain.com"
               }.FromCertificate(certificate));

            //Instantiate the Service (Could be any of the Google Api Services)
            var service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = serviceCredential,
            });

            // Define parameters of request.
            UsersResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.List();
            //Set the Domain of the Request
            request.Domain = "domain.com";

            // List users.
            var users = request.Execute().UsersValue;
            users.Select(u => u.PrimaryEmail).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```